# запуск метода элемента listview, который на экране

Tags: android, listview, imageview

нужно загружать картинку в элементы listview, но так как элементов может быть много, загружать их все сразу не очень разумно, как сделать так, чтобы метод запускался только у тех жлементов, что на экране, пробовал так:

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
           // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "scrollState = " + scrollState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            for(int i = firstVisibleItem; i <= visibleItemCount; i++){
                element.get(i).loadCover();
            }
            list.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

но загружаются только первые 6 картинок, а дальше все

Comment: Вы глубоко заблуждаетесь в своем убеждении, что они грузятся все сразу. Под дебагом в адаптере можете проверить. Изобретаете костыль.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что они из сети грузятся)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобной(Относительно. Ленивая асинхронная загрузка изображений) есть маленькая библиотека https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Проблема вашего кода - вы считаете что visibleItemCount - общее кол-во элементов в адаптере, но это кол-во видимых элементов. Т.е. после шестого элемента вы запускаете цикл с параметром i=7;i<6.

Можно сделать так. Хотя метод onScroll и плохо работает при быстрой прокрутке.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
     if(((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) && totalItemCount > 0)){
        loadNewData();
     }
     list.invalidate();
 }
```

или слегка поправить ваш код

```
for(int i = firstVisibleItem; i <= (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount)&&i<=totalItemCount; i++){
            element.get(i).loadCover();
        }
```

Comment: Либо сделать так как написали ниже. Практичнее, удобнее, быстрее,понятнее.

Comment: вылетает с ошибкой, выскакивает за приделы

Comment: Поправил. i <= (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount)&&i<=totalItemCount;

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, только нужно строгое неравенство)))

Answer (score 3):

загрузку картинок организовать стоит организовать в методе getView, так же стоит использовать паттерн ViewHolder для кэширования элементов списка. Вот небольшой пример как это можно организовать

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    //если convertView == null,
    // значит этот вью элемент еще ни разу не загружался, инфлэйтим его 
    //и сохраняем во view holder
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //list_item - это ваш лэйаут для элемента списка
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    //находим imageView и записываем во viewHolder
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    //сохраняем ссылку на viewholder в convertView
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
    //convertView!=null - значит этот вью элемент уже загружался, можно его переиспользовать, достаем из него ссылку на viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 
    //загрузку картинки делаем с помощью библиотеки http://square.github.io/picasso/ , она же отвечает за кэширование
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(viewHolder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

class ViewHolder{ ImageView imageView;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если загрузка картинки у вас запускается в методе `getView` адаптера, то будут загружаться только картинки элементов, отображающихся на экране. При скроле новые элементы отображаются и их картинки начинают загружаться. Никаких слушателей скрола тут не надо.